# I cannot make the onmouseout function work

Tags: javascript, html, function, onmouseout

I cannot make the onmouseout function, that should make disappear some text from the "demo" paragraph, run in this simple rock, paper, scissors game I'm working on, any idea as to why it won't work, the function I'm talking about is in the head script, and the elements interested by it are the ones inside the "objects" div:

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ROCK, PAPER OR SCISSORS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css for rock paper scissors.css"/>
<script> 
var userChoice;
function game(){   
var computerChoice=Math.random();
if (computerChoice <=0.33){
    computerChoice="rock";
}else if (computerChoice<= 0.66){
    computerChoice="paper";
}else{
    computerChoice="scissors";
}
var winner = function (choice1,choice2){
    if(choice1===choice2){
        return "It's a tie!";
    }else if(choice1==="rock"){
        if (choice2==="paper"){
             return "Paper wins!";
        }else if(choice2==="scissors"){
            return "Rock wins!";
        }
    }else if(choice1==="paper"){
        if(choice2==="rock"){
            return "Paper wins!";
        }else if (choice2==="scissors"){
            return "Scissors win!";
        }
    }else if (choice1==="scissors"){
        if (choice2==="rock"){
            return "Rock wins!";
        }else if(choice2==="paper"){
            return "Scissors win!";
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You: "+userChoice+" "+"<br>"+"Computer: "+computerChoice+"<br>"+ winner(userChoice,computerChoice);
};
function clear(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= " ";
};
function descriptionpaper(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<span>Paper</span>: this is the worst enemy of any rock";
};
function descriptionrock(){
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<span>Rock</span>: preatty damn hard, impossible to cut";
};
function descriptionscissors(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<span>Scissors</span>: they cut things...that's about it";
};

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>ROCK, PAPER OR SCISSORS . . .<br><span>CHOOSE ONE WISELY . . .<span></h1>
            <div class="flame" title="Fire makes this intense...even more than it alredy is"></div>
            <div class="flame" title="Fire makes this intense...even more than it alredy is"></div>
            <div class="flame" title="Fire makes this intense...even more than it alredy is"></div>
            <div id="objects">
                <div class="object" id="paper"><a onmouseover="descriptionpaper()" onmouseout="clear()" onclick="userChoice='paper';game()"><img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/sheet-paper-clipart-free-vector-blank-white-paper-cartoon-clip-art_114492_Blank_White_Paper_Cartoon_clip_art_medium.png"/></a></div>
                <div class="object" id="rock"><a onmouseover="descriptionrock()" onmouseout="clear()" onclick="userChoice='rock';game()"><img src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/12/22/00/03/rock-576669_640.png"/></a></div>
                <div class="object" id="scissors"><a onmouseover="descriptionscissors()" onmouseout="clear()" onclick="userChoice='scissors';game()"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT8/okg/dT8okg6Te.png"/></a></div>    
            </div>
            <p id="demo"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
h1
{
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:impact;
}
#demo
{
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:impact;
    margin-top:-82px;
}
span
{
    font-size: 60px;
}
.flame
{
    height:350px; 
    display:inline;
    content:url("http://vector-magz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/fire-vector.png");
    width:30%;
    padding-left:15px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:15px;
}
img
{
    height:150px;
    width:250px;
}
#objects
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-180px;
    height:300px;
}
.object
{
    width:33%;
    display:inline;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:90px;
}
#rock
{
    padding:50px;
}
#scissors
{
    padding:0px;
}
.wrapper
{
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to remove white spaces from the name of css file, just for any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `clear` method in javascript so you can't name your function as it. Change your function name to anything else and your problem is gonna be solved.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, really fast answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine after I moved it to jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/4s273tek/1/

Keep in mind it's usually best to keep javascript/css/html separate to prevent from having to dig through a mess to find errors. That being said, it should work.

```
>
```

Comment: I'll keep it mind thank you :) since, as you can probably tell from my code, I'm a beginner, do you see anything I could improve in the way I write code? any kind of advice will help

Comment: Absolutely! Everyone has to start somewhere and you have some good concepts down already. The only reason I mention the separation of the code is because it's SO easy to not do when you're building something, but speaking from  personal experience, as your code grows it gets harder to maintain and develop. One of the things I noticed is that you seem to be closing all your lines with semi-colons. It's good practice, but you actually don't have to put them after every closing bracket } you usually only have to when you're calling an anonymous function in a method, otherwise it closes by itself!